# несколько действий по тапу на ячейку в tableview

Tags: swift, button, tableview

всем привет. Есть ячейка в tableview, на которой лежат label и кнопка. Мне надо по нажатию на кнопку менять саму кнопку, а по нажатию на ячейку - переходить на другой view. Переход на view делаю через didSelectRow. Подскажите, какие есть варианты работы с ячейкой, чтобы осуществить этот функционал?

Comment: Вариантов много. Можно на кнопку повесить делегат и обрабатывать его. Или посмотрите вот здесь, например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1232212/swift-Как-определить-по-какому-view-было-сделано-касание

Comment: Если кнопка написана кодом, то приделать к ней addTarget(...) с указанием на метод, который будет менять кнопку. Если кнопка не кодом, а на сториборде, то выводите Action и в нем меняете вид кнопки. Про ячейку у вас и так все решено, по тапу переходите через present(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

спасибо всем за помощь. Сделала так:

в подклассе Cell прописала:

```
    var buttonTap: () -> ()  = { }

     let checkButton: UIButton = {
           let button = UIButton()
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return button
        }()
        
        @objc func didTapCheckButton() {
           buttonTap()
        }
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
            super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
            contentView.addSubview(checkButton)
            checkButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapCheckButton), for: .touchUpInside)
            
        }
 public func refresh(_ model: TaskModel) {
      
        switch model.isComleted {
        case true:
           checkButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "check"), for: .normal)
        case false:
            checkButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle"), for: .normal)
            
        } 
      
    }

В подклассе TableView:
.....
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as? TaskTableViewCell {
            
           
            var task = tasksArray[indexPath.row]
            self.tasksArray[indexPath.row] = task

            cell.refresh(task)
            
            cell.buttonTap = {
                task.isComleted = !task.isComleted
                switch task.isComleted {
                case true:
                    cell.checkButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "check"), for: .normal)
                   
                case false:
                    cell.checkButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle"), for: .normal)
                    
                }
            }
            
            return cell
        }
        
        return UITableViewCell()
        
    }
```